# Notification do not dismiss till it clicked by the user

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using the below code to generate the notification in my application

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = MainActivity.this;

        notifManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotification = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(mContext).setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                .setTicker("Launch download").setContentTitle("Downloader").setContentText(content)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent());

        mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        mNotification.setAutoCancel(true); 
        notifManager.notify(UPDATE_PROGRESS, mNotification.build());


    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {

        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReceiver.class);
        //i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

Note:- I am using [NotificationCompat2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2) by Jake Wharton.

Now this code works fine except when a new a Notification arrives it dismisses the old notification even if it is not read by the user.

**My Question**

How to show all the notification in the status slidingdrawer till it is not read by the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A notification will be replaced by another if they have the same id. Change the id in

```
notifManager.notify(id, mNotification.build());
```

to display several notifications.